# I can not include css file to my Spring BOOT

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have spring boot project bit I can not include css file.
It is structure of my project:

```
main
 -java
   -DemoApplication.java
   -Initializer.java
   -WebAppConfig.java
 -resources
   -static
     -css
      -test.css
   -templates
    -start.html
   -WEB-INF
    -web.xml
```

Start point class of spring boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebApplicationInitializer class for initialize configs:

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
                new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

configs file where place resource mapping:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
    }
}
```

It is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/test.css" th:href="@{/css/test.css}" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<!--@thymesVar id="message" type=""-->
<p th:text="${message}" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

it is css

```
.h1{

    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

When I get link I see my page but css has not

Comment: You're configuring of things that Spring Boot will configure for you, including the resource handler which may well be the problem. By default, Spring Boot automatically makes anything in `src/main/resources/static` available and configures a `DispatcherServlet` for you. Try deleting your `web.xml`, and your `Initializer` and `WebAppConfig` classes.

Comment: I agree with @AndyWilkinson, you should keep it simple, keep spring work do the work.
Anyways, the problem here is related to a maven conception. src/main/resources, will not be created in your final jar/war. Maven will add it to the target classpath. If you unzip your generated jar/war you'll will see it at the top-level and not in a resources folder.
Maven info: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-starters

Start from  any of the projects in the sample. And then add CSS in the static folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")         // expose under /resources
        .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/"); // everything in /resources/static
}
```

and then you're trying to link it via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/test.css" th:href="@{/css/test.css}" media="screen"/>
```

which can't work cause the url should be `@{/resources/css/test.css}`.

Besides that I do agree to the comment of Andy: you are manually configuring things that Spring Boot already does for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just have to remove the annotation **@EnableWebMvc**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
    }
}
```